# Undefined 'map' for nilClass using two models inside a form - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, erb, formbuilder

I have a models name `Menu`

```
class Menu < ApplicationRecord
  validates_presence_of :name

  has_many :menus_ingredients
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :menus_ingredients
end
```

And I want to connect it to `Ingredients`

```
class Ingredient < ApplicationRecord
  include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper

  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_presence_of :price_per_num_of_unit
  validates_presence_of :num_of_unit
  validates_presence_of :unit
end
```

Therefore, I need a tables, that connect them both. Calls, `MenusIngredient`

```
class MenusIngredient < ApplicationRecord
  validates_presence_of :menu_id
  validates_presence_of :ingredient_id
  validates_presence_of :qty

  belongs_to :menu, optional: true
  belongs_to :ingredient
end
```

Next, I need to be able to add new Menu with MenusIngredient in the same form. I use this form.

```
<h1> New Menu </h1>
<%= form_with model: @menu do |form| %>
  <div>
    <%= form.label :name %>
    <%= form.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <% for i in 0..9 %>
  <div>
    <%= form.fields_for :menus_ingredients do |mi| %>
      <%= mi.label :menus_ingredients %>
      <%= mi.collection_select :ingredient_id, @ingredients, :id, :name, :prompt => "Select ingredients" %>
      <%= mi.text_field :qty, placeholder: "unit in gram" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <% end %>

  <div>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

but then, I got error like this.

[undefined map for nilClass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7zv6.png)

What should I do? Thank you

Here is what my Controller looks like

```
class MenusController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @menus = Menu.all
  end

  def show
    @menu = Menu.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @menu = Menu.new
    @menu.menus_ingredients.build
    @ingredients = Ingredient.all
  end

  def create
    @menu = Menu.new permit_params

    if @menu.save
      redirect_to @menu
    else
      render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  private

  def permit_params
    params.require(:menu).permit!
  end
end
```

Comment: Looks like some validation issue while creating menu, and rendering new form in else block. You need to set `@ingredients` before rendering new form in create action.

Comment: I remove validate presence of menu_id, it works yeah, i do not really need that validation as well.  thank you. @SampatBadhe